# How to get the changes of an <select> tag stored in database using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Unfortunately I have to ask one more question:
I want to create a User Management Control for my CMS and I have a table, which dynamically shows all users of the database with their roles. This works fine.

I also can display a button when something changed (either the role was changed or a user was removed). But my last problem is, how can I store the changes into database. Google couldn't help me with answering, how to get the id of the .remove() rows to update my database. My second problem is, that I have no idea why my ajax doesn't work, so I cannot get the updated values of the `<select>` tags.

I hope that someone can help me finally finishing this project.

Here is my code user.php

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
include("db.php");
session_start();
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"editor.css\">";


?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
</html>
<?php

    $abfrage= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY id asc");
    //$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage) or die( mysql_error() ); 
    echo "<table>";
    echo"<caption>Mitglieder<br></caption>";
    echo"<table border=\"1\" style=\"width:300px\">";
     echo "<th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Rolle</th>
        <th>Funktionen</th>";
    //loop, um alle Nutzer zu identifizieren    
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($abfrage))
{

  echo "<tr id =\"".$row->id."\">";
  echo "<td align=center>",$row->id,"</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>" ,$row->Name,"</td>";
  echo "<td align=center>",$row->Vorname,"</td>";
  //Vorbelegung
  echo "<td align=center><select onChange = \"saveChanges()\" id =\"selections\"><option selected = \"selected\">",$row->Rolle,"</option>";
  //loop, um alle Rollen zu identifizieren. AKTUELL: doppelte Rollen werden noch doppelt angezeigt. Eventuell Rollen auslagern.
  $file = mysql_query("SELECT Rolle FROM user WHERE 1");
    while ($role = mysql_fetch_row($file)) 
    {
        if ($role[0]!= $row->Rolle) {
              echo "<option value=".$role[0].">",$role[0],"</option>";
        } 



    }

  echo "</select></td>";

  echo  "<td align=center><button type = \"button\" onCLick = \"deleteUser(".$row->id.")\">Löschen</button></td>";


}
echo "</table>";
echo "<button type = \"button\" style = \"display:none\" id = \"change\" onClick = \"saveChanges(".$row->id.")\">Änderungen speichern</button>";
?>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  //Hier wird der gewählte User nur durch eine fadeOut Animation ausgeblendet, aber nicht gelöscht! Der Button zum Speichern wird sichtbar
    function deleteUser(id){

      $("#"+id).fadeOut(350, function(){

      $(this).remove();
      $("#change").show();

    });

    }

    function saveChanges(id){

    $("#change").show();
     $.ajax({
     url: 'saveUserChanges.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
    selections: $("#selections").val(),
    id: $("#"+id).val()
    }   
    });



} 




  </script>

</html>
```

**I added the definitions for the AJAX**
This my saveUserChanges.php.

```
  <?php
session_start();
echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"forms.css\">";

/**
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"]))
{
    echo "Bitte erst <a href=\"login.html\">einloggen</a>";
    exit;
}
**/

include ("db.php");

$_SESSION["id"] = $_POST["id"];
$_SESSION["rolle"] = $_POST["selections"];

$sql = "UPDATE user SET Rolle = '".$_SESSION["rolle"]."'
                                        WHERE id = '".$_SESSION["id"]."'"; 
$update = mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Thank you in advance!

Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: just put the proper labeling in your AJAX data call, ala `{ id: $("#selections").val(), selections: your value here }`, then just access it in your PHP script as you normally would do and continue on with your update query in there, since you haven't started it yet, why not use PDO with prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the fields:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'saveUserChanges.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        selections: $("#selections").val(),
        id: $("#"+id).val()
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I am going to test it. Do you also know how to delete the removed users from database?

Comment: @Headjordan: What do you mean by delete? LIke having an "X" next to their name and when you click that it removes them from the database?

Comment: I have two issues: first of all I unfortunately do not know, why the changes of the <select> tag don't be stored in the database. The Ajax works and I cannot find any mistake in the saveUserChanges.php. Secondly: At the moment I can hide the User by using the delete button, but actually it is only removed by the .remove () of jQuery. But I want to get the id of the "removed" User to add this id to the Ajax to delete the User from database. Is this possible?

Comment: If the code in your question is complete for saveUserChanges.php, then you're not actually running the update query.  You're saving the query to `$sql`, but then not doing anything with it.  Deleting would work just the same as updating, just create a second Ajax call sending the user ID to a different script that runs `DELETE FROM user WHERE id = `

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your effort @petema3. It was my mistake. I forgot to copy the $sql query. It still doesn't work:( but I have no idea why. To the other thing with the users: I know that I have to do nearly the same but I don´t know how to get the id of an element which is already removed by jQuery. Sorry, I am a Beginner in web development.